# Google Maps KML refresh

Tags: maps, kml

I have an issue with refreshing KML files the usual way with ?v=timestamp addon to the URL.

Though it is suggested to use this method and it perfectly makes sense, I keep getting 414 code (Request-URI Too Large) on background produced URLs like:
GET http://mt1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=sr&lyrs=kml%3Acb0qzV.... with garbled hexes afterwards, so it's some google thing.

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Your entire GET request should be less than 2k characters. Can you provide an example of the URL you are having trouble with (including the full timestamp parameter)?

Comment: The issue is the same as described and answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489042/414-request-uri-too-large-error-google-maps-v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been 3 years since, but I just ran into this and I should properly close it. So, to quote on my comment above:

The issue is the same as described and answered here:
[414 Request URI Too Large Error Google Maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489042/414-request-uri-too-large-error-google-maps-v3)